# Is there a limit to how many "OR" conditions I can enter in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, operators

Ok so I have a block of code in WordPress that has "OR" conditions inside of the "elseif" statement. here is the code:

```
   <?php } elseif($index == 1 || $index == 8 || $index == 9 || $index == 16 || $index == 17 || $index == 20 || $index == 21) { ?>
```

So the code works great up until `$index == 20 || $index == 21`

Is there a limit on how many times I can use `||` in the elseif statement?

Comment: There is no limit, other than practicality.

Comment: No limits, but easier ways to do this, such as if(in_array($index, [1,8,9,...]))

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker, I'm going to try that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no limit of OR statements inside your if clause. Keep in mind, that the more ORs you get, readability will decrease. There is ALWAYS a better solution then just adding more and more ORs.

For your example above, a better solution would be to check if $index is inside an array of possible values like a so:

Instead of

```
if ($index == 1 || $index == 2 || $index == 3) { /* ... */ }
```

you can do

```
if (in_array($index, [1, 2, 3])) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks so much I did that, but the weird quirk of any index after 16 doesn't work still

Comment: What do you mean by that? It should work for every kind of value.

Comment: the indexes are selected up until ```elseif(in_array($index, [17,21,25])) ```

Comment: Still makes no sence to me. In your code above there isnt even 25, but there is 17 and 21.

Comment: I know I added in more indexes

Comment: I cant simply tell why it is not working. Dump you $index before the  if. There must be something wrong in the code above the if, because I know that this has to work.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a limit. Just make sure it's readable.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `in_array()` function instead. That way the code is often more compact and easier to read and understand at the same time:

```
if (in_array($id, [1, 8, 9, 16, 17]))
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thanks so much I did that, but the weird quirk of any index after 16 doesn't work still

Comment: @MikeL5799 That has to be some other issue. There definitely is no such limit. Please take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the actual issue is if you get a php error. If your code simply does not do what you expect it to do, then most likely you have a logical error in it.